# Why the trunc function of C shows me an error?

Tags: c, math, truncation

When i tried to run the trunc function in C it gives me an error that says **undefined reference to `trunc'** how to resolve this error?

the error code is here:

`` /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTANPox.o: in function `floatmod': temp1.c:(.text+0x3a6): undefined reference to `trunc' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ``

Comment: Did you link with `-lm`

Comment: Note: where to find the information that you need to link with `-lm`? [It says so in the man page.](https://linux.die.net/man/3/trunc)

Comment: @Jabberwocky  I don't know what is -lm sir

Comment: libm is the standard math library on unixy OSes.

Comment: @Shawn sir how to link libm with our program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I compile code below with `gcc main.c`, then I see this error (which is similar to yours)

```
/tmp/ccbouRK0.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `trunc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and compile works with `gcc -lm main.c` (where you see how to use `-lm`).

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   double f=9.8;
   int i;
   i=trunc(f);
   printf("%i",i);
   return 0;    
}
```